# Registro de fechas de creación y modificación en una tabla de usuarios

Tags: mysql, trigger

Estoy creando una base de datos sobre una tienda de abarrotes (productos de primera necesidad) por lo tanto tengo una tabla llamada usuario donde cada usuario debe tener distintos permisos, la cuestión es que quiero almacenar cuando se cambie un usuario o se modifique cierto usuario, ¿cómo debería hacer en ese caso?

```
CREATE TABLE usuario(
  id int primary key not null,
  Nombre varchar (25),
  Apellido varchar (50),
  Direccion varchar (100),
  Telefono varchar (20),
  Login varchar (20),
  psw varchar (6),
  fecha_creacion datetime,
  fecha_actualizacion datetime,
  Usuario_creacion datetime,
  Usuario_actualizacion datetime
 );
```

Comment: Al menos empieza a resolverlo, intenta algo para que podamos ayudarte a continuar: Crea la tabla, prepara un ejemplo y vete leyendo sobre disparadores: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html

Comment: CREATE TABLE usuario(
id int primary key not null,
Nombre varchar (25),
Apellido varchar (50),
Direccion varchar (100),
Telefono varchar (20),
Login varchar (20),
psw varchar (6),
fecha_creacion datetime,
fecha_actualizacion datetime,
Usuario_creacion datetime,
Usuario_actualizacion datetime
);

Comment: Estara bien de esa manera?

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Answer (score 2):

Como el tema de disparadores es relativamente complejo, te adelanto la solución en este fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/63dtpoyu Pero es importante que tengas en cuenta que intentar dar con una solución es mucho más que crear una tabla. Tendrías que haber ido al manual e intentar escribir algo de código.

La idea es crear una tabla para los datos históricos `historico_usuario`, los modificados, porque los nuevos los tendrás en la tabla `usuario`:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS historico_usuario(
  id int not null,
  Nombre varchar (25),
  Apellido varchar (50),
  Direccion varchar (100),
  Telefono varchar (20),
  Login varchar (20),
  psw varchar (6),
  fecha_creacion datetime,
  fecha_actualizacion datetime,
  Usuario_creacion datetime,
  Usuario_actualizacion datetime,
  f_mdf datetime
);
```

A continuación creas el **procedimiento almacenado** que, dado un `id`, te copie el dato al histórico:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE rellena_historico_usuario(v_id int)
BEGIN
  DECLARE n int;
  SELECT
    COUNT(*) INTO n
    FROM usuario
    WHERE id = v_id;
  IF n>0 THEN
    INSERT INTO historico_usuario
      SELECT *,NOW() FROM usuario
        WHERE id=v_id;
  END IF;
END;
```

Una vez este punto, ya puedes definir los **disparadores** de **antes** del cambio, ya sea actualización o borrado:

```
CREATE TRIGGER usuario_update_before
  BEFORE UPDATE ON usuario
  FOR EACH ROW
  CALL rellena_historico_usuario(OLD.id);

CREATE TRIGGER usuario_delete_before
  BEFORE DELETE ON usuario
  FOR EACH ROW
  CALL rellena_historico_usuario(OLD.id);
```

Ahora únicamente te queda hacer las comprobaciones:

```
INSERT INTO usuario (id,Nombre) VALUES (1,'Julián'),(2,'Pedro');
UPDATE usuario set Nombre='Paco' WHERE id=1;
DELETE FROM usuario WHERE id=2;
```

Y ver si obtienes el resultado que esperabas: https://dbfiddle.uk/63dtpoyu